# Trying to find hyperlinks by scraping

Tags: html, r, web-scraping

So I am fairly new to the topic of webscraping. I am trying to find all the hyperlinks that the html code of the following page contains:
https://www.exito.com/mercado/lacteos-huevos-y-refrigerados/leches

So this is what I tried:

```
url <- "https://www.exito.com/mercado/lacteos-huevos-y-refrigerados/leches"
webpage <- read_html(url)
html_attr(html_nodes(webpage, "a"), "href")
```

The result only contains like 6 links but just by viewing the page you can see that there are a lot more of hyperlinks.

For example the code behind the first image has something like: `<a href="/leche-entera-sixpack-en-bolsa-x-11-litros-cu-807650/p" class="vtex-product-summary-2-x-clearLink h-100 flex flex-column">` ...

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're interested in **all** the hyperlinks of the website or only the product hyperlinks?

Comment: @H 1 Yes, but the use of  head is not the problem. @cimentajad I am interested in all the product hyperlinks.

Comment: @DanielOrdoñez I've taken a look. I think you won't be able to do it either with `rvest` or `xml2` because the part of the website that you're interested in is an interactive section of the website. I've nailed down why this can't be done. I'm gonna try to do write down a solution and a complete answer with `RSelenium` at some point today.

Comment: Did you try our solutions?

Comment: @QHarr Yes, thank you very much for the support and sorry for the delay. Both of them work just as stated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to get the `a` tags you're after because that part of the website is not visible to html/xml parsers. This is because it's a dynamic part of the website that changes if you choose another part of the website; the only 'static' part of the website is the top header, which is why you only got 6 `a` tags: the six `a` tags from the header.

For this, we need to mimic the behavior of a browser (firefox, chrome, etc...), go into the website (note that we're not entering the website as an html/xml parser but as a 'user' through a browser) and read the html/xml source code from there.

For this we'll need the R package `RSelenium`. Make sure you [install](https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/docker.html) it correctly together with [`docker`](https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/docker.html), as none of the code below can work without it.

After you install `RSelenium` and `docker`, run `docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1` from your terminal (if on Linux, you can run this the terminal; if on Windows you'll have to download a docker terminal, run it there). After that you're all set to reproduce the code below.

## Why you're approach didn't work

We need to access the 5th `div` tag from the image below:

[image: div_args]

As you can see, this 5th `div` tag has three dots (`...`) inside, denoting that there's code inside: this is precisely where **all** of the bottom part of the website is (including the `a` tags that you're after). If we tried to access this 5th tag using `rvest` or `xml2`, we won't find anything:

```r
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

lnk <- "https://www.exito.com/mercado/lacteos-huevos-y-refrigerados/leches?page=2"

# Note how the 5th div element is empty and it should contain the lower
# part of the website
lnk %>%
  read_html() %>%
  xml_find_all("//div[@class='flex flex-grow-1 w-100 flex-column']") %>%
  xml_children()
#> {xml_nodeset (6)}
#> [1] <div class=""></div>\n
#> [2] <div class=""></div>\n
#> [3] <div class=""></div>\n
#> [4] <div class=""></div>\n
#> [5] <div class=""></div>\n
#> [6] <div class=""></div>
```

Note how the 5th `div` tag doesn't have any code inside. A simple html/xml parser won't catch it.

## How it can work

We need to use `RSelenium`. After you've installed everything correctly, we need to setup a 'remote driver', open it and navigate to the website. All of these steps are just to make sure that we're coming into the website as a 'normal' user from a browser. This will make sure that we can access the rendered code that we actually see when we enter the website. Below are the detailed steps from entering the website and constructing the links.

```r
# Make sure you install docker correctly: https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/docker.html
library(RSelenium)

# After installing docker and before running the code, make sure you run
# the rselenium docker image: docker run -d -p 4445:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox:2.53.1

# Now, set up your remote driver
remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
  port = 4445L,
  browserName = "firefox"
)

# Initiate the driver
remDr$open(silent = TRUE)

# Navigate to the exito.com website
remDr$navigate(lnk)

prod_links <-
  # Get the html source code
  remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>%
  read_html() %>%
  # Find all a tags which have a certain class
  # I searched for this tag manually on the website code and saw that all products
  # had an a tag that shared the same class
  xml_find_all("//a[@class='vtex-product-summary-2-x-clearLink h-100 flex flex-column']") %>%
  # Extract the href attribute
  xml_attr("href") %>%
  paste0("https://www.exito.com", .)

prod_links
#>  [1] "https://www.exito.com/leche-semidescremada-deslactosada-en-bolsa-x-900-ml-145711/p"
#>  [2] "https://www.exito.com/leche-entera-en-bolsa-x-900-ml-145704/p"                     
#>  [3] "https://www.exito.com/leche-entera-sixpack-x-1300-ml-cu-987433/p"                  
#>  [4] "https://www.exito.com/leche-deslactosada-en-caja-x-1-litro-878473/p"               
#>  [5] "https://www.exito.com/leche-polvo-deslactos-semidesc-764522/p"                     
#>  [6] "https://www.exito.com/leche-slight-sixpack-en-caja-x-1050-ml-cu-663528/p"          
#>  [7] "https://www.exito.com/leche-semidescremada-sixpack-en-caja-x-1050-ml-cu-663526/p"  
#>  [8] "https://www.exito.com/leche-descremada-sixpack-x-1300-ml-cu-563046/p"              
#>  [9] "https://www.exito.com/of-leche-deslact-pag-5-lleve-6-439057/p"                     
#> [10] "https://www.exito.com/sixpack-de-leche-descremada-x-1100-ml-cu-414454/p"           
#> [11] "https://www.exito.com/leche-en-polvo-klim-fortificada-360g-239085/p"               
#> [12] "https://www.exito.com/leche-deslactosada-descremada-en-caja-x-1-litro-238291/p"    
#> [13] "https://www.exito.com/leche-deslactosada-en-caja-x-1-litro-157334/p"               
#> [14] "https://www.exito.com/leche-entera-larga-vida-en-caja-x-1-litro-157332/p"          
#> [15] "https://www.exito.com/leche-en-polvo-klim-fortificada-780g-138121/p"               
#> [16] "https://www.exito.com/leche-entera-en-bolsa-x-1-litro-125079/p"                    
#> [17] "https://www.exito.com/leche-entera-en-bolsa-sixpack-x-11-litros-cu-59651/p"        
#> [18] "https://www.exito.com/leche-deslactosada-descremada-sixpack-x-11-litros-cu-22049/p"
#> [19] "https://www.exito.com/leche-entera-en-polvo-instantanea-x-760-gr-835923/p"         
#> [20] "https://www.exito.com/of-alpin-cja-cho-pag9-llev12/p"
```

Hope this answers your questions

Answer (score 2):

The data, including the urls, are returned dynamically from a [GraphQL query](https://graphql.org/) you can observe in the network tab when clicking <kbd>Mostrar más</kbd> on the page. This is why the content is not present in your initial query - it has not yet been requested.

---

**XHR for the product info**

The relevant XHR in the network tab of dev tools:

[image]

The actual query params of the url query string:

[image]

You can do away with most of the request info. What you do need is the `extensions` param. More specifically, you need to provide the `sha256Hash` and the base64 encoded string value associated with the `variables` key in the `persistedQuery`.

---

**The [SHA256 Hash](https://md5hashing.net/hash/sha256)**

The appropriate hash can be extracted from at least one of the js files which essentially governs the set up. An example file you can use  is:

`https://exitocol.vtexassets.com/_v/public/assets/v1/published/bundle/public/react/asset.min.js?v=1&files=vtex.store-resources@0.38.0,OrderFormContext,Mutations,Queries,PWAContext&files=exitocol.store-components@0.0.2,common,11,3,SearchBar&files=vtex.responsive-values@0.2.0,common,useResponsiveValues&files=vtex.slider@0.7.3,common,0,Dots,Slide,Slider,SliderContainer&files=exito.components@4.0.7,common,0,1,3,4&workspace=master`.

The query hash can be regex'd from the response text of an xhr request to this uri. The regex is explained [here](https://regex101.com/r/VdC27H/5/) and the first match is sufficient:

[image]

To apply in R, with `stringr`, you will need some extra escapes in e.g. `\s` becomes `\\s`.

---

[The Base64 encoded product query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

The base64 encoded string you can generate yourself with the appropriate library e.g. it seems there is a [`base64encode`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/caTools/versions/1.17.1/topics/base64encode%20%26%20base64decode) R function in `caTools` package.

The encoded string looks like (depending on page/result batch):

`eyJ3aXRoRmFjZXRzIjpmYWxzZSwiaGlkZVVuYXZhaWxhYmxlSXRlbXMiOmZhbHNlLCJza3VzRmlsdGVyIjoiQUxMX0FWQUlMQUJMRSIsInF1ZXJ5IjoiMTQ4IiwibWFwIjoicHJvZHVjdENsdXN0ZXJJZHMiLCJvcmRlckJ5IjoiT3JkZXJCeVRvcFNhbGVERVNDIiwiZnJvbSI6MjAsInRvIjozOX0=`

Decoded:

`{"withFacets":false,"hideUnavailableItems":false,"skusFilter":"ALL_AVAILABLE","query":"148","map":"productClusterIds","orderBy":"OrderByTopSaleDESC","from":20,"to":39}`

The `from` and `to` params are the offsets for the results batches of products which come in batches of twenty. So, you can write functions which return the appropriate sha256 hash and send a subsequent request for product info where you base64 encode, with the appropriate library, the string above and alter the `from` and `to` `params` as required. Potentially others as well (have a play!).

---

**The xhr response:**

The response is json so you might need a json library (e.g. [jsonlite](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html)) to handle the result (UPDATE: Seems you don't with R and `httr`). You can extract the links from a list of dictionaries nested within `result['data']['products']`, as per Python example, where `result` is the json object retrieved from the xhr with `from` and to `params`.

---

**Examples:**

Examples using R and Python are shown below (N.B. I am less familiar with R). The above has been kept fairly language agnostic.

Bear in mind, whilst I am extracting the urls, the json returned has a lot more info including product title, price, image info etc.

---

**Example output:**

[image]

---

**TODO:**

1. Add in error handling
2. Use Session objects to benefit from re-use of underlying tcp connection especially if making multiple requests to get all products
3. Add in functionality to return total product number and loop structure to retrieve all (Python example might benefit from decorator)

---

**R (a quick first go):**

```
library(purrr)
library(stringr)
library(caTools)
library(httr)

get_links <- function(sha, start, end){
  string = paste0('{"withFacets":false,"hideUnavailableItems":false,"skusFilter":"ALL_AVAILABLE","query":"148","map":"productClusterIds","orderBy":"OrderByTopSaleDESC","from":' , start , ',"to":' , end , '}')
  base64encoded <- caTools::base64encode(string)
  params = list(
    'extensions' = paste0('{"persistedQuery":{"version":1,"sha256Hash":"' , sha , '","sender":"vtex.store-resources@0.x","provider":"vtex.search-graphql@0.x"},"variables":"' , base64encoded , '"}')
  )

  product_info <- content(httr::GET(url = 'https://www.exito.com/_v/segment/graphql/v1', query = params))$data$products
  links <- map(product_info, ~{
     .x %>% .$link
  })
  return(links)
}


start <- '0'
end <- '19'     
sha <- httr::GET('https://exitocol.vtexassets.com/_v/public/assets/v1/published/bundle/public/react/asset.min.js?v=1&files=vtex.store-resources@0.38.0,OrderFormContext,Mutations,Queries,PWAContext&files=exitocol.store-components@0.0.2,common,11,3,SearchBar&files=vtex.responsive-values@0.2.0,common,useResponsiveValues&files=vtex.slider@0.7.3,common,0,Dots,Slide,Slider,SliderContainer&files=exito.components@4.0.7,common,0,1,3,4&workspace=master') %>%
  content(., as = "text")%>% str_match(.,'query\\s+productSearch.*?hash:\\s+"(.*?)"')%>% .[[2]] 
links <- get_links(sha, start, end)
print(links)
```

---

**Py:**

```
import requests, base64, re, json

def get_sha():
    r = requests.get('https://exitocol.vtexassets.com/_v/public/assets/v1/published/bundle/public/react/asset.min.js?v=1&files=vtex.store-resources@0.38.0,OrderFormContext,Mutations,Queries,PWAContext&files=exitocol.store-components@0.0.2,common,11,3,SearchBar&files=vtex.responsive-values@0.2.0,common,useResponsiveValues&files=vtex.slider@0.7.3,common,0,Dots,Slide,Slider,SliderContainer&files=exito.components@4.0.7,common,0,1,3,4&workspace=master')
    p = re.compile(r'query\s+productSearch.*?hash:\s+"(.*?)"') #https://regex101.com/r/VdC27H/5
    sha = p.findall(r.text)[0]
    return sha

def get_json(sha, start, end):
    #these 'from' and 'to' values correspond with page # as pages cover batches of 20 e.g. start 20 end 39

    string = '{"withFacets":false,"hideUnavailableItems":false,"skusFilter":"ALL_AVAILABLE","query":"148","map":"productClusterIds","orderBy":"OrderByTopSaleDESC","from":' + start + ',"to":' + end + '}' 
    base64encoded = base64.b64encode(string.encode('utf-8')).decode()
    params = (('extensions', '{"persistedQuery":{"sha256Hash":"' + sha + '","sender":"vtex.store-resources@0.x","provider":"vtex.search-graphql@0.x"},"variables":"' + base64encoded  + '"}'),)
    r = requests.get('https://www.exito.com/_v/segment/graphql/v1',params=params)
    return r.json()

def get_links(sha, start, end):
    result = get_json(sha, start, end)
    links = [i['link'] for i in result['data']['products']]
    return links

sha = get_sha()
links = get_links(sha, '0', '19')
#print(len(links))
print(links)
```